# javascript how insert "empty" to array?

Tags: javascript, arrays

```js
var array = new Array(5);
array[0] = 1;
array[1] = 1;
array[3] = 1;
array[4] = 1;
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(0)); //true
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(1)); //true
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(2)); //false
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(3)); //true
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(4)); //true
```

I want to insert array that have unsetted element.

```js
var array = [1,1]
var arrayToInsert = new Array(3);
arrayToInsert[0] = 1;
arrayToInsert[2] = 1;
array.splice(1, 0, ...arrayToInsert);
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(0)); //true
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(1)); //true
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(2)); //true, I want to make it false.
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(3)); //true
console.log(array.hasOwnProperty(4)); //true
```

How keep unsetted element after I splice(insert) array that have unsetted element?

Comment: There is no `empty` value in JavaScript.

Comment: there's no such a thing, u can use 'empty' as string

Comment: The console output "empty" there is no actual empty value. That is just what the browser does when all the indexes are undefined.

Comment: @Cid That's a browser/snippet artifact; if you run it in the console it will display it as stated in the post.

Comment: There is a way to do what the OP is really asking.

Comment: I can't tell what the OP is really asking.

Comment: @Quentin I suspect the question is about how to put a "hole" in an array, as if the index had never been assigned a value (like a freshly-created empty array). The answer is to use `delete`. That way `.forEach()` etc will skip that index. Why? I don't know.

Comment: Possibly, but even that smells of being an XY problem.

Comment: Why do you want to remove an index from an array in this way?

Comment: @Ben I make some library for array, I just want to keep array as it is after insert.

Comment: That's not how this works, plain and simple. An array with index `0` and index `2` set is equivalent to `[1, undefined, 1]` for all intents and purposes, most certainly for spreading and most forms of iteration.

Comment: @coloud Are you aware that the "normal" way to empty an item in an array is to set the value associated with the index to `undefined` (or `null`), and that the `empty` description is just Chrome's way of indicating that there is a missing property with an index less than the `length` property of the array?

Comment: I think I was wrong. I thought it was important to keep the empty element.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure to understand your question, but if you want to unset a value from your array (so, setting it as undefined), you can delete the array element:

```js
const a = [1, 2, 3, 4];
console.log(a);

delete(a[2]);
console.log(a);
```

Comment: Note that, depending on the browser, this still shows up as `undefined` on the console, and it will behave that way too with traditional `for (var i = 0; i < a.length; i++)` loops…

Comment: I want to insert array that have unsetted element. Isn't there way to automate delete unsetted elements?

Comment: @coloud There's no such thing as "inserting unsetted elements". You either insert elements or you don't. If you do insert elements, those elements have to be *something*. And they'll be `undefined`, which is the value for "nothing".

Answer (score 0):

If you want to insert a value meaning "empty" into an array, simply assign the special value of [`undefined`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/undefined) to your chosen position in the array.

```js
var array = ['a','b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
var arrayToInsert = ['', undefined, '⛱']

array.splice(1, 0, ...arrayToInsert)

console.log(array)
console.log(Object.keys(array))
console.log(array.length)
```

When you see the word "empty" written in the console, is used by Chrome to indicate the absence of a property corresponding to an index.

Note that **the printing of the word "empty" to the console is a peculiarity of Chrome** and is not part of the JavaScript standard.

To remove one of the index properties from an array, you use the `delete` keyword.

Note how doing so looks different in the consoles of Chrome, Safari and Firefox:

[image: Chrome]
[image: Safari]
[image: Firefox]